# Document Class "convert" does not work with SVG Package

Tags: packages, svg

When creating a standalone document to convert it into a PNG file, I get an error if I include the [SVG](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg) package.

**MWE**

```
%\documentclass{standalone}
\documentclass[convert={density=720,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{se}

\end{document}
```

Without the convert option it works perfectly. With the convert option I get the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty
Package: svg 2020/05/07 v2.02f (include SVG pictures)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/04/19 v3.30 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.478 \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}
                                 \relax
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

I have tried to compile using both, pdftex and luatex, and get the same result.

Does anyone know what the reason for this error is, and how to solve it? Thanks for the help beforehand!

Comment: What is in `se.svg`?

Comment: Also are you sure this is the actual error and not just the end of the log? Because I get this error just over the line where `svg.sty` is loaded: `Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape
(standalone)              is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').`

Comment: No, I can confirm that problem. It seems to be related to the `svg` package, not the `\includesvg{se}`. If I replace `\includesvg{se}` by `test` in your MWE and compiles with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` I get the same error

Comment: You probably need to report this to the maintainer of the svg package. I'm not sure it makes sense loading `scrbase.sty` in this context or what ever it is `svg` is trying to do.

Comment: Try to move the configuration out of the class options. svg is using the keyval parser from KOMA and seems to get confused by the option. `\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{convert={density=720,outext=.png}}` could work.

Comment: Ok. Perfect! Many thanks @daleif. I will do so. (PS. It was the end of the log. Sorry for the misclarification).

Comment: @Ulrike at least then it complains that the svg I used was not made by Inkscape.

Comment: Reported as an issue for svg. https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/29

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer your answer has worked perfectly. If you want to post it, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho it is a standalone error. It cleans up the `\@classoptionslist` but not the list from xkeyval, and then scrbase fails on it. You can redefine the list:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=720,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\makeatletter 
\def\XKV@classoptionslist{} %empty or with whatever option you want to pass on.
\makeatother 

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{se}

\end{document}
```